# AJAX, postbacks and browser refreshes

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have created a user control to handle adding comments to certain business entities, like contacts and customers.  Works great ... except for one issue.

I am using a ListView control to edit and delete comments, and a separate area, on the same user control to add a new comment.  All of this is wrapped in an UpdatePanel.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is my scenario ... the user adds a new comment ... the page does a postback, the data is successfully saved, and the ListView control is updated to show the new comment.  Now, if the user **refreshes** the browser, it will naturally postback again and will add another duplicate record.

Any ideas on how best to prevent this?

Comment: How are you adding the new comment? It is part of the "Add the comment" button event handler?

Comment: Yes ... all this works ... but if the user presses their refresh button on their browser it will add another record.

Comment: There's a nice article on the subject [here](http://aspalliance.com/687_Preventing_Duplicate_Record_Insertion_on_Page_Refresh.all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://www.theserverside.com/patterns/thread.tss?thread_id=20936) pattern.  Basically instead of letting the postback send the data, redirect to the page.  That way, if a user refreshes, s/he is refreshing the GET command rather than the POST.

---

Sorry.. missed the UpdatePanel piece.  Make sure that your submit button is also within that UpdatePanel.  A page refresh would not affect your AJAX call, but when the button is outside the panel, it's doing a regular postback so you would be sending the Add Request again.

Comment: @Wayne Wouldn't this defeat the whole purpose of the AJAX?  Wouldn't the entire page refresh if I did a redirect?

Comment: This would defeat the use of AJAX

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used ASP.NET in a few years, but you should wrap your "do this on postback" code in  `Page.IsPostBack`:

```
if(IsPostBack) {
    //do your data-saving code...
}
```

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(VS.71).aspx)